# compilation error while using swap method for queue in C++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, queue

I have `error: ‘class std::queue<int>’ has no member named ‘swap’` while compiling following code

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <queue>          // std::queue

int main ()
{
  std::queue<int> foo,bar;
  foo.push (10); foo.push(20); foo.push(30);
  bar.push (111); bar.push(222);

  foo.swap(bar);

  std::cout << "size of foo: " << foo.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << "size of bar: " << bar.size() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3` for compiling this code,can anyone have a idea for this error?

Comment: So what error do you get? It works fine for me.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'm getting error: ‘class std::queue<int>’ has no member named ‘swap’ and now its resolved by std::swap(foo, bar);

Comment: OK, you need C++11 support, so compile with `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
std::swap(foo, bar);
```

It appear that since c++11, you have std::queue::swap

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/swap-free/

g++ 4.6 appears to not accept -std=c++11, so you must upgrade your compiler for this method to work.

[edit]

g++ 4.6 accepts -std=c++0x to enable c++11